# Itext7 PdfAction.CreateGoTo() Links not working in final document

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext7

I've parsed html into a PDF and created a table of contents from the Header tags.  The bookmarks in the document work fine, but clicking on the line in the table of contents doesn't do anything.  The cursor doesn't change icons like it does if I put a URL in the link.

I used Itext RUPS to inspect the final PDF and the named destinations are in the final file.

I tried hard coding a couple of the names in just to see what happens, but they also didn't work.  Putting in .CreateURL and google.com works fine.

The one thing I'm doing that may or may not be an issue is I'm creating the body document, then creating the table of contents and merging the two documents.

Maybe Bruno can make a cameo on this one.

```
    private static List ProcessOutlineChildren(PdfDocument pdfDocument, List tableOfContents, IEnumerable<PdfOutline> pdfOutlines, IDictionary<String, PdfObject> names = null)
    {
        List<TabStop> tabStops = new List<TabStop>();
        tabStops.Add(new TabStop(580, TabAlignment.RIGHT));

        foreach (var o in pdfOutlines)
        {
            ListItem currentOutlineItem = new ListItem();

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.AddTabStops(tabStops);
            paragraph.Add(o.GetTitle());
            paragraph.Add(new Tab());
            paragraph.Add((pdfDocument.GetPageNumber((PdfDictionary) o.GetDestination().GetDestinationPage(names))).ToString());
            paragraph.SetAction(PdfAction.CreateGoTo(o.GetDestination()));
            
            currentOutlineItem.Add(paragraph);

            if (o.GetAllChildren().Any())
            {
                currentOutlineItem.Add(ProcessOutlineChildren(pdfDocument, new List(), o.GetAllChildren(), names));
            }

            tableOfContents.Add(currentOutlineItem);
        }

        return tableOfContents;
    }



    public class CustomOutlineHandler : OutlineHandler
    {
        //PDF's require a unique name for destinations, this is how the actions/bookmarks jump to a location.  
        protected override string GenerateUniqueDestinationName(IElementNode element)
        {
            string destinationName = base.GenerateUniqueDestinationName(element);
            if ("p".Equals(element.Name()))
            {
                destinationName = destinationName.Replace(GetDestinationNamePrefix(), "paragraph-prefix-");
            }

            return destinationName;
        }
    }
```

//From my main method converting things into PDF.

```
                    OutlineHandler customOutlineHandler = new CustomOutlineHandler().PutAllTagPriorityMappings(priorityMappings);
                    customOutlineHandler.SetDestinationNamePrefix("destination-name-");
                    properties.SetOutlineHandler(customOutlineHandler);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, currently all the targets are destination-name-# and the # increments through the document, so they are all unique, so i've tried putting "destination-name-32" etc in one of the creatActions with no luck

Comment: All good, just glad I'm not getting shot down for asking a dumb question out of the gate :)

Comment: Hi, can you attach the HTML you are trying against and make the code more ready to be run on a third party environment? You have attached `ProcessOutlineChildren` method declaration, but how do I run it? Which parameters does one need to pass?